# Assure synchronous execution of nested Arrays within arrays (Promise.all - in Promise.all)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, mean-stack

I have a problem in assuring the synchornous execution of an array which is executed within another array. The first array is NOT directly link to the "Nested" one - it just assures the the second ("nested") array is executed as many times, as the first one has recrods resp. documents.

To illustrate the Problem - here is the code I am talking about

```
  Promise.all(
    room.connections.map(connection => {
      Question.find({room: room.title}).then(questions => {
        return Promise.all(
          questions.map(question => {
            if (question.answers.length !== 2) {
              question.answers.push({ email: connection.userId, own: "", guess: "" });
              console.log('SAVE ANSWER');
              return question.save();
            }
          }),
        )
      });
    })
  ).then(() => {
    console.log('SENDING GAME READY TO BOTH!!! !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
    io.of("/game")
      .in(room.title)
      .emit("GameReady", true);
    ack(false);
  })
```

So as you see - I am inserting answers into a question array. Besides that there should be inserted as many answers, as I have active connections in another Collection.
I have tried the code above, but obviously the first promise.all resolves, as soon as the two connections where iterated through - without assuring the all answers have already been inserted/saved.
I have initially tried to make the whole thing without the first Promise.all - but had the problem that the "socket.emit" part would then be executed twice (because I have 2 connections in my array usually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outermost lambda (`connection => { ... }`) has a statement body (because the body is surrounded by curly braces), but doesn’t contain a `return` statement, so the expression `room.connections.map(...)` is evaluating to a collection full of `undefined` values. And something like `Promise.all([ undefined ])` will immediately resolve.

Try returning `Question.find(...)` from the outer lambda. That way, the outermost call to `Promise.all` will receive as argument a collection that’s properly populated with promises.